# C# Collection Get True of False by matching items

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, collections

I am facing a real time business problem in one of my project. the scenario is i have to allow users to do alterations based on current application state. I will describe the flow briefly as following,

There are 4 stages in application Stage 1, Stage 2, Stage 3 and Stage 4 and there are couple of statuses that associated with above stages such as A,B,C,D,E,F,G and etc...

based on statuses i have to allow to do alterations in each stage following are the respective stages and statuses which allow edit,

1. Stage 1 => A,B,C
2. Stage 2 => A,C,G
3. Stage 3 => F,E
4. Stage 4 => A,B,C,D,E

The problem i am facing is is there a way to get the editable indicator by passing the Stage and status to collection in c# and if that status is an editable for the passed stage then it should return true or else false

is this possible through C# Dictionary or Hashtable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Evaluating the appropriate collections behaviour in c# i decided to achieve this by using a dictionary

```
IDictionary<string, HashSet<string>> sets = new Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>>();
        sets.Add("Stage 1", new HashSet<string>{ "A","B","C"});
        sets.Add("Stage 2", new HashSet<string>{ "D","E"});

public static bool GetAllowed(string stage,string status, IDictionary<string,HashSet<string>> allowedSets)
    {
        return allowedSets[stage].Contains(status);
    }

Console.WriteLine(GetAllowed("Stage 1", "A", sets)); // returns true
Console.WriteLine(GetAllowed("Stage 2", "A", sets)); //returns false
```

Comment: From a performance perspective, this is worse than my proposal. The `string.Contains()` method is less efficient than using `HashSet<T>.Contains()`', not even counting the extra commas in your data that only slow things down. Even if you must use a string to denote a given stage, you're better off using a `Dictionary<string, HashSet<T>>` instead of a `Dictionary<string, string>`. (There is also the issue of you passing the dictionary instance by-reference for no apparent reason, but that's tangential to the main point).

Comment: Thanks @PeterDuniho I have changed the the Implementation of my approach as stated in the above answer based on your comments thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this:

```
private static readonly HashSet<char>[] _allowed =
{
    new HashSet<char> { 'A', 'B', 'C' },
    new HashSet<char> { 'A', 'C', 'G' },
    new HashSet<char> { 'F', 'E' },
    new HashSet<char> { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E' },
};

bool Allowed(int stage, char status)
{
    // Assume stage is 1-based, so subtract 1 for array index
    return _allowed[stage - 1].Contains(status);
}
```

?

Comment: rather than using a hashset dictionary will be handy in terms of performance in .Net and i have implemented this using a dictionary thanks for the approach

Comment: Why would you use `Dictionary<T>` instead of `HashSet<T>`? They both use hash-tables, and your string-based approach (as I see in your own answer) is slower than a hash-table lookup.